# How to manually add Excel columns headers for a generated spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have developed an excel sheet using c# gridview. How do I add a header row and set column names via code. This is my current code...

```
protected void ExportToExcel1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Clear();
   Response.Buffer = true;
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
   Response.Charset = "";
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
   using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
   {
       HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

       //To Export all pages
       GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
       bindgrid();

       GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

       foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
       {
           cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
       }
       foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
       {
           row.BackColor = Color.White;
           foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
           {
               if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
               {
                   cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
               }
               else
               {
                   cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
               }
               cell.CssClass = "textmode";
           }
       }

       GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

       //style to format numbers to string
       string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
       Response.Write(style);
       Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
       Response.Flush();
       Response.End();
   }
}
```

Comment: Cleaned up spelling mistakes and grammar.  Made the title clearer. Removed the sql tag. Removed extraneous request for help.

Comment: What have you tried?  This sounds like a Googleable problem, but I don't have domain knowledge with asp or gridview.  Also how is this related to Excel?